# How can I locate a resource file for a Kitura server?

Tags: kitura

I would like to load a file from disk in my Kitura server, but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to locate a file. Can anyone suggest how you would locate a file included with the server?

Note I am not talking about serving a static resource here, like a HTML page. I want to load the file into the server from disk, so I can work with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find this IBM-Swift recently released package useful: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/FileKit

Answer (score 1):

Outside of using another third-party library, the URL API in Foundation is your best bet at loading files from file system (NSBundle isn't complete on Linux). Unfortunately, that means your server app will have to know the paths to files on the system, which can make code portability a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks. I do see Kitura forming these paths itself. Shame they haven't made that public. Guess I can just rebuild that code myself.

Comment: @Drew McCormack
You can see some examples of common paths (i.e., for resolution of relative file paths) [here](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Configuration/blob/master/Sources/Configuration/PathUtilities.swift).

The main problem is that Swift Package Manager doesn't yet have support for packaging resource files (i.e., Java lets you bundle resource files in the JAR). The end result is that the Swift application itself has to load the files from disk using file paths, and these paths can differ on your development system (i.e. macOS) vs. your runtime system (i.e., Linux Docker container).